# Can't access private member.. but member is explicitly declared public

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class called `MusicPlayer` declared like so:

```
class MusicPlayer : public MIDIRenderer {
public:
    void Play(std::vector<Note> &notes);
[and other stuff but that doesn't matter]
};
```

Where `MIDIRenderer` is can be found [here](http://cfugue.sourceforge.net/docs/html/_midi_renderer_8h_source.html#l00031).

I need to use `MIDIRenderer`'s `OnNoteEvent` (declared on line 76)

The exact call that I'm making is in a `for` loop:

```
MIDIRenderer m;
std::vector<Note>::iterator i = notes.begin();
for (i; i != notes.end(); i++) {
    m.OnNoteEvent(NULL, &(*i));
}
```

But I'm getting an error on the `OnNoteEvent` line that `error C2248: 'CFugue::MIDIRenderer::OnNoteEvent': cannot access private member declared in class 'CFugue::MIDIRenderer'`. But `OnNoteEvent` is public?
How can I use the `OnNoteEvent`? Basically, I'm trying to play `Note` objects.

Comment: It's private. Default accessor it's `private`. You can see below `public` keyword on code.

Comment: gdi i'm blind I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in C++, if not otherwise specified, class members are private. So OnNoteEvent *is* private.

Answer (score 1):

No, `OnNoteEvent` and all the other event handlers in class `MIDIRenderer` are declared private. In fact there is no accessibility declaration, which defaults to `private`.

I'm not familiar with `CFugue`, so I cannot direct you to the right API to use for your use case, but this is not what you ought to do.

Answer (score 0):

`OnNoteEvent` *is* private.  All members of a `class` that do not have an access specifier default to `private`.